# How to import long strings at different column positions with SSIS?

Tags: ssis

Our provider stores our survey data in the following format

1. Columnnames for each survey

*Example:*

```
|v1         |v2|v3|t1
|CompanyName|v1|v2|v3|t1|
```

2. Data for each person

*One dataset for survey1*

```
|1        |2|1|I work in the metal industry
```

*One dataset for survey2*

```
|MyCompany|4|2|4|I work as a programmer
```

For each survey I get an identifier to consume the rest api and get the data in json. That is the way I know which data belong to which columninformation.

```
RestRequest("/datasources/{identifier}/columns", Method.GET)
RestRequest("/datasources/{identifier}/data", Method.GET)
```

I consume this with `SSIS` and my problem is that there are up to 400 columns and there are columns like `t1` that can be at any position and hold up to 5000 character strings (`t1` is an open question). Within `SSIS` I could now define each column as string with 5000 in length and set all columns in my stagging table to `varchar(max)` but this would have huge consequences to the performence. That is why I would like to ask if there is another way to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not assume it will have huge consequences to performance. Handling this is what Varchar(Max) is for and it's very unlikely to have any impact.

Regarding your specific question about alternatives however, the only one is to use sparse column sets. This allows you to pack a lot of potential but usually null columns into one actual XML column. Then they only get stored inside if they are actually used. They can be selected from directly using their column name, though if you Select * then you only get the raw XML column.

Microsoft documentation is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/cc280521.aspx